# Unsatisfiable Constraint for NSLayoutConstraint changed programmatically - swift

Tags: swift, anchor, nslayoutconstraint

I'm setting up a constraint in viewDidLoad and then changing its constant when the keyboard shows up.
This is the initial set Up

```
bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomBar, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
```

Then I change the constant when I receive a keyboard notification:

```
@objc func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        
        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
        
        bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardHeight : 0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration:0.1, delay: 0 , options: .curveEaseOut , animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        } , completion: {(completed) in
        })
    }
}
```

It's interesting because I'm only changing the constant and not adding another constraint. Nevertheless I receive this warning in console:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282ae4ff0 UIView:0x109f11110.bottom == UIView:0x109f13240.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282ae8050 UIView:0x109f11110.bottom == UIView:0x109f13240.bottom - 291   (active)>"
 )
```

Which basically states that the constraints I have don't work well togheter.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:
This is the code I use to add the bottom bar programmatically:

```
let bottomBar:UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

In ViewdidLoad()

```
view.addSubview(bottomBar)
bottomBar.addSubview(fontView)
bottomBar.addSubview(colorPicker)
fontView.pin(to: bottomBar)
colorPicker.pin(to: bottomBar)

 func setUpConstraints(){
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bottomBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        bottomBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        bottomBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
 ])
}
```

Comment: Is `bottomBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` true or false?

Comment: @Sweeper it is false

Comment: Are you using a storyboard for the view?

Comment: No, It’s all created programmatically

Comment: This looks like a bug, since when changing the constant the old value should automatically be set to inactive. Anyway, maybe you should try to do that yourself. Set  `bottomConstraint?.isActive = false`, then change the constant and activate it again `bottomConstraint?.isActive = true`

Comment: @StackGU - double check your code... from what you've posted, you are creating a `bottomViewConstraint` but in your keyboard show/hide code you're setting `bottomConstraint?.constant`.

Comment: @Andre3000 I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I'm doing it, what's wrong with that? I'm trying to update the constant of the constraint.

Comment: @Stackgu I think @DonMag refers to the fact that `bottomViewConstraint` and `bottomConstraint` are two different variables.

Comment: @StackGU Also, you might try to create create a new constraint, instead of changing the constant value of the current one. But be careful to set the current one's `isActive` property to false before creating the new constraint and activating it.

Comment: Yes it's a typo, I corrected it right now

Comment: @StackGU - it looks pretty clear that somewhere in your code you're creating two bottom constraints. Maybe show more of your code (actual code, without typos)?

Comment: @StackGU - did you find the double-bottom-constraint you are adding? so you can close this question?

Comment: I haven't yet, I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: @StackGU - update your post and include the code where you add `bottomBar` and set its constraints -- I'm assuming you're setting Leading / Trailing and Height... and *probably* bottom.

Comment: I added it, yes, I'm adding those 3 constraints but not bottom

Comment: You have at least two mistakes. First, you are referring to `bottomViewConstraint` which is a different constraint. Second, you are originally configuring `bottomBar` inadequately, as it has no `top` or `bottom`, just a `height`. It is unclear from what you have shown where the bottom constraint would ever come from — and the debug message says there are actually two of them. Perhaps you created them in the storyboard or something.

Comment: @matt as I said before, bottomViewConstraint doesn't exist, it was a typo I had in the code. The only bottom constraint I have is bottomConstraint.
Referring to your 2nd statement, the bottom constraint for bottomBar is the actual bottomConstraint that I activate in viewDidLoad

Comment: If it's a typo then fix it in the question. Don't leave the question with fake stuff in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to make it a bit easier for you...

Start simple.

This code creates a text field near the top, and a red "bottomBar" view at the bottom. When the keyboard shows or hides, the bottomBar's bottom constraint constant is updated (tap anywhere on the view to dismiss the keyboard):

```
class ConstraintTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let bottomBar = UIView()
    
    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        // add a text field
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        bottomBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomBar.backgroundColor = .red
        
        view.addSubview(tf)
        view.addSubview(bottomBar)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain text field 80-pts from Top, Width: 240, centerX
            tf.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            tf.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            tf.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            // constrain bottomBar Leading and Trailing, Height: 70-pts
            bottomBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            bottomBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            bottomBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70.0),
            
        ])
        
        // create and add the bottom constraint
        bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomBar, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)

        // or, use more modern syntax...
        //bottomConstraint = bottomBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        //bottomConstraint.isActive = true
        
        // keyboard show/hide notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.handleKeyboardNotification(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                               object: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.handleKeyboardNotification(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                               object: nil)

        // add a "tap on the view to dismiss the keyboard" gesture
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
    }
    
    @objc func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification){
        
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
            
            let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
            
            bottomConstraint.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardHeight : 0
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration:0.1, delay: 0 , options: .curveEaseOut , animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            } , completion: {(completed) in
            })
        }
    }
    
    @objc func didTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
}
```

If this runs without auto-layout errors / warnings (which it will), then start adding in your other UI elements (and supporting code) ***one at a time***. If / when you get the constraint conflict again, you'll know exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start all from scratch and see what happens with the constraints and where the bottom constraint is causing errors

Comment: I finally found out what it was, really stupid mistake, I added two snippets of code for initialising the view controller: one in viewDidLoad (like I'm used to do) and the other in the custom init(nibName..), this resulted in creating the double constraint. Anyway thank you for the support!

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing enough information, so it is necessary to guess. Here is one guess. When you say:

```
fontView.pin(to: bottomBar)
colorPicker.pin(to: bottomBar)
```

You create *two* `bottomBar` bottom constraints. When you say:

```
bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomBar, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
```

you create a *third* bottom constraint.

Then when you say

```
bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardHeight : 0
```

you change one bottom constraint but not the others. Perhaps that accounts for the conflict.

Another possibility is that perhaps you call the `view.addConstraint` twice in some way that you have not shown us. Again, that would mean you are changing one bottom constraint but not the other.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, I took in consideration both of your options but it seems none of them is working for my case, I'm noticing tho that the warning occurs whenever I change the constant of the bottomConstraint (If I set it without changing constant it works fine) so I was thinking that maybe it could be the fact that the notification is called twice whenever it shows or not

Comment: Well the notification can be called many times. But that is not the problem. These are _two different constraints_. You can see that clearly in the error message. You need to believe what it is telling you. This is not a system bug. This is _your_ bug. Trust me, you will not figure this out until you believe that. There are many ways to work out what your constraints are; use them. Use the View Debugger. Give your constraints identifiers (names). Do anything to debug.

Comment: I finally found out what it was, really stupid mistake, I added two snippets of code for initialising the view controller: one in viewDidLoad (like I'm used to do) and the other in the custom init(nibName..), this resulted in creating the double constraint. Anyway thank you for the support!

Comment: Well done. So my last paragraph was right! You see the value of the lesson here. Believe the runtime! It says there are two constraints, there _are_ two constraints, it's as simple as that.